# create table using python objects

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 in a Python script to extract data from a client's spreadsheet.  My client is planning to add on to the spreadsheet, so my sqlite code should generate its columns based on the headers I extract from the first line.  How do I do this?  This is my naive attempt:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('./foo.sql')
c = conn.cursor()
for line in file:
  if line[0] == 'firstline':
    # Below is the line in question
    c.execute(""" create table if not exists bar(?, ? ,?); """, lineTuple)
  else:
    c.execute(""" insert into bar values (?, ?, ?); """, lineTuple)
```

Comment: I am aware of the distinction.

Comment: Making a database look like a spreadsheet for import purposes is the first step toward getting people off the spreadsheet. Also, for the record, having a script routinely call `create table` creeps me out because then, in this case, you spend your time debugging the trash (spaces, special characters, unicode, newlines, etc.) the users put into the column headings.

Comment: Using headers from the spreadsheet is a bad idea.  You'll have to convert them to a valid sql identifier in a consistent way.  Generate column names like 'c1', 'c2' etc. instead and keep a mapping of spreadsheet header -> sql column names somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, csv module of python can help you to extract file data.

First, convert your spreadsheet in csv format (save as csv command) with appropriate delimiter.

then, try below code snippet:

```
import csv
file_ptr = open('filename.csv','r');
fields = range(0, total number of columns in file header)
file_data = csv.DictReader(file_ptr, fields, delimiter=',')
for data in file_data:
   print data
   # data will be in dict format and first line would be all your headers,else are column data
   # here, database query and code processing
```

Hope, it will be helpful.